# Oprofile - using operf to show INST_RETIRED and l1d_replacement events in opreport

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, oprofile

Host: Ubuntu 14.04
Opef version: 0.9.9

I would like to have two events shown in opreport so that I enter the following command to run operf:

```
operf ./l1thrash -e l1d_replacement:10000 -e INST_RETIRED:10000 --separate=cpu
```

After some seconds, the terminal shows  "Profiling done"

And then I typed:

```
opreport
```

I did not specify the path because the man page indicates that the data is saved in the "oprofile_data" automatically.

However, the output did not show "l1d_replacement" and "INST_RETIRED" event.

```
CPU: Intel Haswell microarchitecture, speed 3.5e+06 MHz (estimated)
Counted CPU_CLK_UNHALTED events (Clock cycles when not halted)with  a unit mask of 0x00 (No unit mask) count 100000
CPU_CLK_UNHALT...|
samples|      %|
------------------
 708080 100.000 l1thrash
CPU_CLK_UNHALT...|
  samples|      %|
------------------
   707010 99.8489 l1thrash
     1068  0.1508 no-vmlinux
        1 1.4e-04 ld-2.19.so
        1 1.4e-04 libc-2.19.so
```

I believe I miss something here to get these two events appeared on the opreport.

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to have these two events in opreport while using operf.

The command is shown in the following:

```
operf -e l1d_replacement:xxxxxx -e INST_RETIRED:xxxxxx --separate-c ( execute your application here ) 

opreport cpu:1
```

You should have these two events appeared.